# Slow SQL query using OR

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query, postgresql-performance

The following query is 10x faster if I delete the "OR" clause.

```
WITH RECURSIVE toeng(lang1, english, syn, enid) AS
(SELECT lang1.word, english.word, english.synonym, english.id  
FROM lang1 INNER JOIN english ON lang1.english_id=english.id
UNION
SELECT CAST('' as VARCHAR(255)), english.word, english.synonym, english.id
FROM english JOIN toeng ON toeng.syn=english.id OR toeng.enid=english.synonym)
....
```

The goal of the query is to retrieve all the parents/children of an initial set of nodes recursively.
Is there a way to make it faster? I tried to split it into multiple joins but I can't find something that is totally equivalent to that. I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: DO you have any indexes on `english` or `toeng`?  If so, what columns?

Comment: `english` is correctly indexed, `id` is its primary key and `synonym` is a foreign key to `id`. as for `toeng`, it is defined recursively so I don't know if/how I can index it.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info then [edit] your question and add the missing information.

Answer (score 0):

> query is 10x faster if I delete the "OR" clause

In that case, make sure that you have proper index created on `toeng.enid` (means `english.id`) and `english.synonym`. Generally, you should have index for the columns you are trying to use in `JOIN ON` clause, `WHERE` clause, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your comment that `english.id` is indexed.  This is good.

The reason your query is slow is because `FROM english JOIN toeng ON toeng.enid = english.synonym` will be slow.  Without an index on `english.synonym`, the clause forces a full table scan.
The full clause, `toeng.syn = english.id OR toeng.enid = english.synonym` can match some of the records using the `english.id` index, but it still requires a full table scan to pick up the matching `english.synonym` records that *aren't* covered by the index.  The optimizer knows that there's no point using the index if a full table scan is required, so it skips the index altogether.

**Solution:** you will need to add an index on `english.synonym`, either as a standalone index or as part of a [multi-column index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) (adding it to the `english.id` index).

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't created an index on `english.synonym` on purpose, assuming it was created automatically since it's a foreign key to `english.id`. But I just realized this is not true in PostgreSQL (while it is for MySql). I'll give it a try later!